# isotope js hidden div not pushing div down when shown

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I have an isotope thumbnail gallery with 2 filters, 1 sort, and shuffle/unshuffle. In my isotope container, I have 19 thumbnails (items). Each item has a simple "show info" with unstyled checkbox. When checked, it shows hidden div text below the thumbnail. This all works great - no issues to the functionality at all. However, when I check the box which unhides the div below it (but still in item container), it lays on top of the item below it (another item in another container). What I'd like is to have it push the item out of the way. Here's the weird thing - if I check the box and the info appears on top of the item below it...and then I click "unshuffle" (sortBy : 'original-order'), it does push the item out of the way and all is good. But I don't want to constantly push unshuffle for it to act properly. Also, if I uncheck the box to hide the info the items don't move...but if I click unshuffle, they move to where they are supposed to be. Am I an idiot and this is a super easy fix?

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zuhloobie/Lt1hL0p6/5/

Here is code:

```
<div id="headerContainer">
<div class="header">november 2014
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay - so that's not all the code, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fix from DeSandro (thanks!):

Needed to trigger the layout after the layout has changed. In this case when checkbox is clicked.

```
$'.galleryItem input:checkbox').click (function(){
    $container.isotope('layout');
});
```

Here is updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lt1hl0p6/7/

Also deleted window smartresize logic as it was unnecessary.